# Where is vagrant's log file?

Tags: logs, virtualbox, debugging, vagrant, funtoo

I am trying to debug a vagrant- or VirtualBox related problem (see  [taiga-vagrant fails to provide a working taiga environment #21](https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-vagrant/issues/21#issuecomment-157775321)).

The command `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up --debug` prints out plenty of, probably, useful information. Where is this log stored however?

*Edit:* `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` is actually the same as `vagrant up --debug`. I work on/with: Funtoo-Linux, Vagrant 1.4.3 and VirtualBox 4.3.32.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vagrant does not keep any logs.  The output of, for example `vagrant up --debug`, can be redirected to a file like

```
vagrant up --provision --debug &> debug_log
```

---

Fragment from an IRC session in #vagrant at Freenode:

> [18:29] `<NikosA>` ada: really, where is the debug "file" stored, by default? Isn't there any?
>
> [18:29] `<ada>` vagrant does not write to log files

..

> [18:29] `<ada>` virtualbox does
>
> [18:29] `<NikosA>` I am even trying to >>
>   debug_log in the command line, and it simply does not keep any of
>   these valuable details.
>
> [18:29] `<NikosA>` ok, so I'd check for the VBox
>   logs?
>
> [18:30] `<ada>` if you're using the vbox provider, yes

..

> [18:31] `<dtrainor>` NikosA, redirect the output with &>

Comment: Why do we need to have &? I usually just use > but seems it's not sufficient.. I am interesting to learn

Comment: To redirect file descriptors (stdout,stderr) you use >&FD., so to send stderr to stdout add >&1

Answer (score 2):

Per an [answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26391978/4258430), VirtualBox will store logs at `~/VirtualBox VMs/vagrant_box_name/Logs`.